# Emmet autocompletion + Intellisense clashing

Tags: visual-studio-code, emmet

So when I type in an emmet abbreviation like `div.result` which should then expand to `<div className='result'></div>`. However, with Intellisense, VS Code detects that I have a filename called `MovieResults`, and suggests it.

I hit esc because then otherwise, my emmet abbreviation turns into `<div className='MovieResult'></div>`.

The suggestion goes away, but from there, I don't know of any other way to expand the abbreviation, other than setting `"emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true`.

Any ideas on a solution to this? It's just bugging me that I'm trying to name the `className` as `results`, but Emmet isn't offering me an autocompletion for it.

Here are some images of what I'm talking about:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had changed to:

```
 "emmet.showExpandedAbbreviation": "inMarkupAndStylesheetFilesOnly",
```

changing back to the default fixed the issue:

```
 "emmet.showExpandedAbbreviation": "always"
```

Also this will help:

```
"emmet.showSuggestionsAsSnippets": true,
"editor.snippetSuggestions": "top",
```